# Grunt autoprefixer error when using @extent in scss file

Tags: sass, gruntjs, autoprefixer

Error:

```
Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
File .tmp/styles/documentation.css created.
Warning: Can't parse CSS: Missing property value at line 66:21 in .tmp/styles/main.css Use --force to continue.
```

Line 66 points to the following code:

Source:

```
span {
  @extent .md-body-1;
}

p {
  @extent .md-body-1;
}
```

I can't extent a tag in scss? Or is a autoprefixer issue?

Comment: That's correct, you can't `@extent` in Sass because there is no `@extent`.  Double check your spelling.  Voting to close: typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `@extend` not `@extent`

Comment: Thanks. My bad. I will leave this for other noobies: http://www.sitepoint.com/sass-extend-nobody-told-you/